# Trying to understand Sembast with BLoC: events are not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

i'm trying to use Sembast for my diploma project that is a guide on how to create databases. I have a <1mo experience with Flutter and i have no idea how to do things or what to use. The database is supposed to hold the blogs for the guide. I ran into a problem with BLoC:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:dbug/data/fruit.dart';

@immutable
abstract class FruitEvent extends Equatable {
  const FruitEvent([List props = const []]) : super(props);
}

class LoadFruits extends FruitEvent {}

class AddRandomFruit extends FruitEvent {}

class UpdateWithRandomFruit extends FruitEvent {
  final Fruit updatedFruit;

  UpdateWithRandomFruit(this.updatedFruit) : super([updatedFruit]);
}

class DeleteFruit extends FruitEvent {
  final Fruit fruit;

  DeleteFruit(this.fruit) : super([fruit]);
}
```

all the names in the fields are from a tutorial and will be changed later.

so the main issues are on `const FruitEvent([List props = const []]) : super(props);` (Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.) and every event (Missing concrete implementation of 'getter Equatable.props'.).

I've tried looking up guides or stackoverflow posts on how to fix it, but couldn't understand how to fix the issue. The main fix i've seen is to write an override, but i couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your @immutable,

Dont Edit your abtract class event.

And if you use Equatable, you need to use proops at every eventclass you create
you can use "pro" type to automate show suggestion to proops.

Hope it can help.

```js
abstract class FruitEvent extends Equatable {
  const FruitEvent();

  @override
  List <Object> get props => [];
}

class LoadFruits extends FruitEvent {}

class AddRandomFruit extends FruitEvent {}

class UpdateWithRandomFruit extends FruitEvent {
  final Fruit updatedFruit;

  UpdateWithRandomFruit(this.updatedFruit);
  
   List<Object> get props => [updatedFruit];
}

class DeleteFruit extends FruitEvent {
  final Fruit fruit;

  DeleteFruit(this.fruit);
  List<Object> get props => [fruit];
}
```